# Lining up header, paragraph and image

Tags: html, css

[image: Ideal layout]
I'm a beginner so having some trouble learning to get things where I want them.

I want to move the paragraph under the header with the top of it lining up with the image and header.

I also want to have to scroll down to see the next section (hydro stuff) instead of it being next to the first section (wind stuff)

I hope that makes sense, TIA.

```css
.re-format {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.re-format img {
  padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.re-format h3 {
  color: #474747;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 40px;
}

.re-format p {
  font-family: candara;
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="re-format">
  <img src="images/wturbine.jpeg">
  <h3>Wind Energy</h3>
  <p>para about wind <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>

  <img src="images/dam2.jpg">
  <h3>Hydro Energy</h3>
  <p>para about hydro <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to add ‘flex-direction:column’ in the ‘re-format’ class

Comment: That kind of works, although literally everything went into one long vertical column :/

Comment: Is the ‘display:inline-flex’ really necessary? Make it ‘display:block’ and see

Comment: If I use display:block, everything goes vertical with or without using flex-direction:column;

Comment: So isn’t a vertical design what you need?

Comment: Each header, img and paragraph I want to line up horizontally, with the paragraph filling up the space under the header and to right of the image. Each header + image + paragraph I'm considering a section. So I want to have to scroll down to see the second section.

Comment: With that markup, you want grid layout, not flexbox.

Comment: either you do this with flexbox or betetr yet with CSS-Grid. But even float world work in this context

Comment: Thanks, I haven't even had a look at CSS-Grid so would probably be best for me to get on that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your desired result image cleared things up.

Try this. Hope you will follow the comments to understand what really happens.

```css
/* display subsection as a flex box; default direction is row */
.subsection {
    display: flex;
}
.subsection-content {
    text-align: left;
    /* add a small padding to the left */
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.re-format {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.re-format img {
  padding: 50px 0 0 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.re-format h3 {
  color: #474747;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  text-align: left;
}

.re-format p {
  font-family: candara;
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="re-format">
  <div class="subsection">
    <!-- bring the image out of the subsection content so it can displayed independent of the right column -->
    <img src="images/wturbine.jpeg">
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <h3>Wind Energy</h3>
      <p>para about wind <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="subsection">
    <!-- bring the image out of the subsection content so it can displayed independent of the right column -->
    <img src="images/dam2.jpg">
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <h3>Hydro Energy</h3>
      <p>para about hydro <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: One finaly question I have is how I can move the paragraph up and closer to the header? :)

Comment: Adjust the `re-format h3` class's `padding-bottom` to a lower value. Like `padding-bottom: 5px'. You can adjust the value `5px` to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the desired effect?

Explanation:

- First, to make the content scroll vertically and not horizontally, set `flex-direction` to `column`.
- Second, I changed a bit the layout of each "title+content" element. Now each of the two elements has its own enclosing div (`.subsection`).
- The image and text inside a subsection are arranged using a horizontal flexbox (there are other ways to do it too).

```css
.re-format {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.re-format img {
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.re-format h3 {
  color: #474747;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 40px;
}

.re-format p {
  font-family: candara;
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subsection-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="re-format">
  
  <div class="subsection">
    <h3>Wind Energy</h3>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <img src="images/wturbine.jpeg">
      <p>para about wind <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="subsection">
    <h3>Hydro Energy</h3>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <img src="images/dam2.jpg">
      <p>para about hydro <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's SO close! How would I put the header above the paragraph rather than above the image?

Answer (score 0):

Like so?

```css
.re-format {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}

.re-format img {
  padding-right: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.re-format h3 {
  color: #474747;
  text-shadow: none;
  padding: 40px;
}

.re-format p {
  font-family: candara;
  color: #474747;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.subsection-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="re-format">
  
  <div class="subsection">
    <h3>Wind Energy</h3>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <img src="images/wturbine.jpeg">
      <p>para about wind <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  
  <div class="subsection">
    <h3>Hydro Energy</h3>
    <div class="subsection-content">
      <img src="images/dam2.jpg">
      <p>para about hydro <br>para about company<br> para about some other stuff</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I'd like to scroll down to each subsection. For example, I can see Wind Energy, the image relating to it and the paragraph about it, but then have to scroll down to see the stuff about Hydro Energy. I'd like the top of the image to line up with the header on the right side, with the paragraph below the header (to the right of the image).

Comment: I've added a link in the original post with my ideal layout